# How can I find the nearest ATM in India?

Tags: applications

There are some applications that can find and locate ATMs but those I tried are not for India or for Indian banks.  Is there an app that supports this for India?

Comment: How about Google Maps?

Comment: i need specifically for ATM, where i can select Bank and can see list of ATMs i want if i do athis in google map it will be time consuming

Comment: Do you know of any app that will work on other Java based non-Android phones ? They're usually .jar or .jad files. You can use those in Android too - just install them via the JAVA app.

AFAIK, there are none at the moment. If it's just a list you need, I suggest you expend the time and effort and collate a list from your bank's website and save it for future use. That way you'll save time as well as data charges.

Comment: Is Google Places out for India? (I don't think so.) One of the main menu items is "ATM".

Comment: @Al: YES! Great find...this question has now made me sit up and take notice of this hidden gem. It worked quite well. And pretty accurate too. It listed all the ATMs I know of and 2 more I didn't, albeit within about 1 KM of my current location and that too without GPS being on (A-GPS / cell-tower tracking only). Recommend you reformat the PLACES suggestion as an answer.

Comment: Turned comment into answer.

Comment: If you have an ATM linked to VISA, you can find ATM all over the world . [Click Here](http://www.visa.com/atmlocator/index.jsp#%28page:home%29) to find ATM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is Google Places out for India?

One of the main menu items is "ATM".

If not, You're probably better off using the website for your bank. If they're good, they've already got a mobile version of the site and one of the primary functions I'd think they'd have is ATM locations.

Answer (score 0):

New app just launched: [ATM Hunter](http://androidcommunity.com/mastercard-launches-atm-hunter-for-android-20110119/)

Don't know how well it covers India.

Answer (score 0):

To find nearest you can visit [ATM LOCATOR](https://www.khojlo.in) this is for India. This will give you the list of ATM around your location and distance of all atm. with map view.

Comment: So, you're the developer of the site? Please mention that in the question; nothing's wrong about that..